# Button disappears when textfield is added in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

I am working on an app where a UITextField is added dynamically to a scrollview. For the scrollview I am using the following code:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + kbSize.height);
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

There are two buttons and they are placed on the scrollview. When I click on the first button, a textfield should be generated between the first button and second button, and the second button should move down.

The problem I am facing:

1) When the textfield is dynamically added, the second button disappears from the scrollview

2) The scrollview does not work after adding the textfield

3) How can I change the size of the scrollview when the textfield is added?

The code for adding textfield I am using is:

```
// below is called every time first button is clicked

// for moving the second button down
CGRect frame;
frame = self.createButton.frame;
frame.origin.y = 269 + Y;
self.createButton.frame = frame;

//adding textfield dynamically
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 156+Y, 280, 30)];
Y = Y+38;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
textField.placeholder = self.keyField.text;
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView addSubview:textField];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of Y here initially?frame.origin.y = 269 + Y;

Comment: try to add contentHeight of scroll view to second button y position + height

Comment: can u show me by editing the above code?

Comment: Do you have auto-layout turned on?

Comment: Hi I have added the code after change. Please check it now

Comment: @SauravNagpal not working

Comment: Can you please share a woking sample code for the problem so that i can test it? or any image ?

Comment: i have the scrollview and adding the textfield code in the above question?

Comment: is the question incomplete? Should i add anything else??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
CGRect frame = self.createButton.frame;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + kbSize.height);
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
CGRect frame = self.createButton.frame;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height);
}
```